# Moderating entries in database django

Tags: django, django-models

Im looking for a package or a way to moderate entries in a database.

I have an ecommerce site and sellers are going to be able to load and edit their items through django-admin ( with their unique ID, single database ), and I want to check/review/moderate these entries before they are posted in the web.

Is this possible ? or is there any other approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Add another field specifying whether or not the item has been moderated, and only show moderated items in the frontend.